# Regex to validate url with port, clarification needed

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a URL using the following regex, in `Java`

```
^http(s*):\\/\\/.+:[1-65535]/v2/.+/component/.+$
```

Test fails using URL: `https://box:1234/v2/something/component/a/b`

I suspect it's the number range that's causing it. Help me understand what am i missing here please?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want to allow port 0?

Comment: You should also be careful with the dot `.` in combination with `+` or  `*` because this will be greedy matching everything that it can reach, e.g. `../../../../../`. Better would be to use `[^/]+` as a replacement for `.+` in your regex.

Comment: If you want it the hard way, you could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html. You can't just write `[1-65535]` to match `1` or `65535`. That says any number `1-6`, or `5` or `3`.

The expression you need is quite verbose, in this case:

```
([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])
```

(Credit to http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)

Another issue is your `http(s*)`. That needs to be `https?` because in its current form it might allow `httpsssssssss://`. If your regex takes public input, this is a concern.

Comment: Using regex to match range is ugly. Just match normally, then extract the port and compare is cleaner and more maintainable.

Comment: Doesn't mean that you must provide one. You can always suggest better ways of doing it (if the better way is regex, then use regex, if better way is something else, then use that).

Answer (score 2):

`^http(s*)` is wrong, it would allow `httpssssss://...`

You need `^https?`

This doesn't affect the given test though.

Comment: Downvoted for "This doesn't affect the given test though." Not a useful answer. Should be a comment.

Comment: @frb Well, it does apply to "Help me understand what am i missing here please?"... just not to the given example.

Comment: @AdriánLópez So it applies to...half of the question, and not the important part (making the regex match the test)

Answer (score 1):

The group `[1-65535]` basically means number from 1 to 6 or 5 or 5 or 3 or 5.
that would even evaluate, but you need an + (or *) at the end of the group.

To match the port more precisely you could use `[1-6][0-9]{0,4}?`. That would get you really close, but also allow p.e. 69999 - the `{m,n}?` is used to specify how often a group can be used (m to n times)

Also take care of that (s*) thing the others pointed out!

That would result in:
`^https?:\\/\\/.+:[1-6][0-9]{0,4}?/v2/.+/component/.+$`